# What is a "limited array"?

Tags: history, interferometry

I'm reading about the history and making of ESO's Very Large Telescope and I've found [this article](https://www.eso.org/sci/publications/messenger/archive/no.50-dec87/messenger-no50-30-32.pdf) that says the scientific community had a choice between three suggestions: a one-piece 16m-telescope, four 8m-telescopes or 16 4m-telescopes. They chose the second solution (four 8m-telescopes), because

> there was a clear trend that some form of limited array was the right direction for the VLT.

I don't understand what *limited array* means. Is it just a name they picked up from radio interferometry, or is it some special method of interferometry being used at the VLT? The article says, that

> the study group [for the VLT] concentrated its efforts on the scientific advantages one could draw from the limited array concept and particularly on interferometry."

Could anyone clear this up for me?

Comment: An array of 4 telescopes is clearly more limited than an array of 16 telescopes. That's all it means.